# How to get the complete URL of a Azure Function from a different function inside the same App Service?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

In Azure Functions, when you create a function, this one gets a unique GET code for calling it. Using a App Service that has two or more functions, I want to, from one of those functions, access the complete URL with the GET code of a different function.

**My example sceneraio**

I have two functions:

- PreSomethingHook
- PostSomethingHook

When "something" happens, `/api/PreSomethingHook?code=ew12e12ew2e` should be called.
I want `PreSomethingHook` to start a long process in an external API which, one of the parameters it receives, is a callback url for when the process finishes. Now, when the process finishes, `PostSomethingHook` should be called and handle the result.

My problem is that I don't know how to obtain the *PostSomethingHook complete url* dynamically, without setting it inside a DB or an environment variable. (Which is what I don't want to do)

To conclude,

How can I obtain a function's URL with it's GET code from a different function inside the same App Service?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options here:

Use function chaining using Durable functions - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sequence

Use the rest api to retrieve the function secrets from inside your function app and invoke the 2nd function directly - https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/eecb26c94952b58b0c848e06042358158bcdce1d/specification/web/resource-manager/Microsoft.Web/stable/2018-02-01/WebApps.json#L3105

Comment: please don't click on this link or your browser will crash, the file loads a lot of info